# Distributions using np.rand and np.randn

Tags: distributions, python

I'm working through the Hands on Machine Learning book by Géron:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Hands-Machine-Learning-Scikit-Learn-TensorFlow/dp/1491962291

As part of the learning material, there is a dplyr jupyter notebook:

https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/tools_numpy.ipynb

I was wondering whether anybody could please explain the difference between the distributions that is outputted in the 'np.rand and np.randn' section. For example, the graphs that are output are as follows:

[image: np.rand and np.randn distributions]

One is clearly the normal distribution curve, but what is the blue line showing?

Grateful for any explanations.

Comment: A good place to start is the documentation. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.rand.html

Answer (score 1):

It's almost a convention that RAND() is uniform distribution, and RANDN() is normal. That's the case in your library, and in many libraries elsewhere. For instance, here's matlab's [randn](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html) and [rand](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) functions. Similar in R: [rand and randn](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/varbvs/versions/2.5-16/topics/rand%2Crandn) functions

Answer (score 0):

I am no Python user but the red line looks like a standard normal distribution and the blue one like a uniform distribution between 0 and 1.

A common way to tackle this kind of question is looking up documentation. I found this, which, if applicable, tells us, that 'rand' is a convenience wrapper for 'random_sample': https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.rand.html

Documentation to 'random_sample': https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.random_sample.html#numpy.random.random_sample
says

> Return random floats in the half-open interval [0.0, 1.0).
>
> Results are from the “continuous uniform” distribution over the stated interval. To sample Unif[a, b), b > a multiply the output of random_sample by (b-a) and add a:

So the documentation and the result are in line. But reading the documentation also told us, that it is an half-open interval and to which side it is open. If you plan to later take eg. a log, that can be very useful information.